Given a number of minutes, check if we should work on rest according to the pomodoro technique
I am trying to calculate if a specific minute is within a pomodoro (work interval) or if it's within a rest interval. Assuming I am taking breaks in the following intervals:

Work for 25 minutes (Pomodoro).
Rest for 5 minutes.
Go to step one until four pomodoros have passed.
Once four pomodoros have passed, instead of resting for 5 minutes, rest for 30.

My first Pomodoro would be $0..25$ and my first small rest in $25..30$. The first ample rest would be in the range of $115..145$.
To calculate if a minute is in rest, I could divide the given minute by the minute when the first rest ends and check if the remainder is greater or equal to the minute where that rest started:
\begin{align*}
  \text{inShortBreak}(m) &= m \bmod 30 \geq 25 \\
  \text{inLongBreak}(m)  &= m \bmod 145 \geq 115
\end{align*}
The problem is that the fifth Pomodoro would be in the $145..170$ range, but according to the previous functions, there would be another small rest at minute 145.
My question is: How can I calculate if a given minute is within the work/rest ranges?

P.D.: I mostly do programming, and I don't have much experience with math. I am sorry if I used the wrong concepts when explaining my problem.

So you have identical cycles of length (25 + 5)*3 + 25 + 30 = 145.
So x = t % 145 gives the value as if you stopped at 145.
Then if x % 25 <= 5, you are in rest
and if x >= 115, you are in rest
Otherwise you are in work.
Maybe this is not a nice solution. I think there is probably no "nice" closed form solution to this, I could be mistaken.

This is what I was looking for. I was close, but I didn't think of it as a 145-minute cycle. I am still curious to know what other "non-nice" solutions look like.
